# how to set the scroll bar for particular column in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Hi i want to set the Horizontal scroll for table in particular column.

here i have created the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/pJ5BR/7235/

i want to set the scroll bar only for last name and age.

i have seen this fiddle and try this way

http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/7/

but this is not help to angularjs

```
.TableScroll { 
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:visible;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}


td, th {
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100px;
}

th:first-child {
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px
}
```

after use this code in

http://jsfiddle.net/vinothsm92/pJ5BR/7237/

can any one solve my issue

Comment: you can use angular datatables .much better then this

Comment: second thing do you want scroll bar for column or row?

Comment: i need horizontal scroll bar.